# Calling an asynchronous function via a Button

Tags: swift, asynchronous, button, aws-amplify

Trying to create a signup button that is asynchronous and the only way I've figured out to not get an error on compiling is by using "Task" but the function is never called when the button is pressed.

```
VStack{
    TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.username)
    TextField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
    TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
    Button("Sign Up", action: {
        Task{ try await viewModel.signUppp }
    })
    Button("Sign In", action: {
        Task{ try await viewModel.signIn }
    })
}
```

```
func signUppp() async {
    let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
    let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
    print("In sign ")
    do {
        let signUpResult = try await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
            username: username,
            password: password,
            options: options
        )
        if case let .confirmUser(deliveryDetails, _, userId) = signUpResult.nextStep {
            print("Delivery details \(String(describing: deliveryDetails)) for userId: \(String(describing: userId))")
        } else {
            print("SignUp Complete")
        }
    } catch let error as AuthError {
        print("An error occurred while registering a user \(error)")
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: when I have just "action: viewModel.signUppp" in the Button parameters, I get the error "Cannot pass function of type '() async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type"

Comment: Try `try await viewModel.signUppp()`

Comment: Since the function `signUppp()` does not throw anything, have you tried just `Task{ await viewModel.signUppp() }` and similarly for `signIn()`, note the `()` and no `try`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This worked, thank you for the help! I was wondering if you could explain why there is no need for "try" and why it would only work with "()" and not without it since there are no parameters.

Comment: To call a `function` in Swift you need to use the `()` where you may have arguments to pass into it.
See, this link for more info and explanations: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

There is no need for `try` because the function `func signUppp() async {...}` does not `throw` any errors.
This is part of the error handling in Swift, see this link for more info and explanations: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html